# How lazy load an external module in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load an external module (I wrote) into a main application, and I've got some errors, but first of all I wanted to ask you whether I have to build into **/dist** the external module first, or I have to use the source files?

Both main and external app/module are written with Angular 5

Error:

```
ERROR in Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20291:23)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15244:60)
    at visitLazyRoute (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31182:104)
    at AotCompiler.listLazyRoutes (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31150:20)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.listLazyRoutes (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:156:30)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:44:36)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:246:66)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (/Users/me/Dev/Work/mobile-shop-frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:537:50)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Comment: First I would migrate to Angular6, the library creation can be done in the same project now.

But for the case of lazy loading a module what I can remember you need to build a package ready to be npm installed

Comment: Other option I already saw is to create a wrapper module in your app that will use the external library you created, and this wrapper you can easily lazy load

Comment: remove your node_module folder and do `npm install` again
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a wrapper module for this external module and then lazy load this wrapper module. Angular doesn’t load external node modules as lazy module so I followed same approach